Required field constraint vs Regular field in CUE language
According to the CUE language official tutorial:

A required field constraint requires that the field be specified as a regular field if it’s exported.
A regular field must be made concrete if it is exported to a data format such as JSON or YAML.

By transitivity, it sounds to me these are the same. Will appreciate an example emphasizing the distinction between the two.
P.S. I also looked the language spec, but still fail to understand.
